# How to control a bezier curve using an armature?

Tags: modeling, animation

Can you explain me how to control a bezier curve using an armature?
The objective would be to be able to bent a cylinder while keeping its initial length and its diameter in order to be able to animate something like this: [image: molecule machine]

A solution has already been made on this link: [How to effectively animate a "lasso"?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78777/how-to-effectively-animate-a-lasso/79076#79076)
But I think an armature would be more suitable.

The animation should give the following result:
Initially, the macrocycle (torus) is located around the first station (green sphere). After a stimulus, the macrocycle moves along the axis (gray tube) and positions itself around the second station (pink sphere, fixed on the axis). Moving the macrocyle causes a tightningof the loop. Thanks to an armature on the axis, I would like to move only the macrocycle according to x (which will follow the axis thanks to a curve modifier according to x) which will cause a tightning of the loop.
Moreover, as this image shows: [image: lasso2]
a peptide (blue tube) is placed on the axis just next to the macrocycle. Initially, it is almost linear, and after the macrocycle has moved around the second station, the tightning of the loop induces a curvature of the peptide. The image shows it well, but in this the shape of the axis does not natural, hence the choice of use an armature...

Thank you for your answers,
Rota.

Comment: The hook modifier can have a bone as a target, try it.

Comment: As far as I know you can't directly control a curve object with armatures, only after converting to mesh

Comment: FYI, in the previous answer I used curves mainly for the sliding blue part. If you don't want it, I think rigging a cylinder will give a better result (more smooth), because hook will 'corner' the hook points

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
I must confess that I am lost in what to do and especially in the order in which I must do.
For now, I created a bezier curve, then an armature with bones on each control point of my curve. Is good ? If so, should I then convert my bezier curve to mesh?
I'll attach the .blend file to make it clearer.
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3268" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3268/)

Comment: Here are two settings: with hooks (hooks to bones) on top and on bottom a cylinder parented with automatic weights. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3269" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3269/)

Comment: @lemon Thank you very much for your response and for your time.
I tried to reproduce your solution on my base file ( [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3275" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3275/) ) but I can not do it ... Can you explain me step by step how to make from this file? Better still, is it possible that you make a video of your computer screen when you do the various manipulations (as in your answer of my previous question)?

Comment: @Rotavap, could you edit your question providing more details about how the animation is to be directed. What I mean: it is always possible to 'hard tune' each animation step and obtain a result, but you may also want to obtain it consistently just manipulating (say) the red torus. How are things about it? What are the latitudes in the torus movement?

Comment: @lemon I have edited my question, I hope that the clarifications provided will help you to see more clearly.